# Ruby variable not read in loop

Tags: ruby, shopify

Ruby newbie getting even more confused.

If I remove the `discountgiven == false` from the 4th line, code in the condition works.

If I add it back, the code doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Is it something wrong in the `discountgiven` variable scope?

```
  discountgiven = false
  Input.cart.line_items.each do |item|
    product = item.variant.product
    if product.tags.include? 'device-ePod' && discountgiven == false
      discount_to_apply = item.line_price * (1.0)
      item.change_line_price(item.line_price - discount_to_apply, {message: 'Free Epod'})
      discountGiven = true
    end
  end
```

Comment: You have `discountgiven` and `discountGiven`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @ElaBuwa : If in an expression of the form `X && Y`, the `X` is considered _true_, the value of the whole expresssion is `Y`. In your case, the expression is `'device-ePod' && discountgiven == false`. Now, `'device-ePod'` is trueish, and hence the expression evaluates to `discountgiven == false`, which is true. The condition in the `if` effectively asks for `if product.tags.include? true`, and this is `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parentheses in conditions:

Change :

```
if product.tags.include? 'device-ePod' && discountgiven == false
```

to

```
if product.tags.include?('device-ePod') && discountgiven == false
```

Your former logic is being evaluated as `if product.tags.include?('device-ePod' && discountgiven == false)`

Also, what spickermann suggested, you probably typo in `discountGiven`. It should be `discountgiven`.